# Redux store and PouchDB not syncing with redux-pouchdb

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, pouchdb

I am trying to get my redux state to be synced to a PouchDB instance, but having trouble with this.

As it seems in the logs, neither is my redux state synced to PouchDB after an action happened, nor is the PouchDB document synced to the redux state on update.

I tried to implement `redux-pouchdb` as it is implemented in [jrzerr/react-redux-pouchdb](https://github.com/jrzerr/react-redux-pouchdb) but neither do I get an error, nor does the sync work.

This is the code I am working with:

*Reducer (modules/mainbase.js):*

```
import { persistentReducer } from 'redux-pouchdb';
export const INPUT_CHANGED = 'mainbase/INPUT_CHANGED'

const initialState = {}

function mainbase (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case INPUT_CHANGED:
            state[action.key] = action.value;
            return {...state}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default persistentReducer(mainbase);

export const inputChanged = (key, value) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: INPUT_CHANGED,
      key: key,
      value: value
    })
  }
}
```

*Root reducer (modules/index.js):*

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux'
import mainbase from './mainbase'

export default combineReducers({
  router: routerReducer,
  mainbase
})
```

*Store (store.js):*

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import rootReducer from './modules'
import { persistentStore } from 'redux-pouchdb'
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb'

export const history = createHistory()

const db = new PouchDB('testproject')

const initialState = {}

const enhancers = [
  persistentStore(db)
]

const middleware = [
  thunk,
  routerMiddleware(history)
]

const composedEnhancers = compose(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  ...enhancers
)

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  composedEnhancers
)

export default store
```

I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mainbase you are updating state directly. This usually does not work well. You should *first* create a copy of the current state, update the copy and return the updated copy as the new state.

Comment: I'm using a spread operator so the state the reducer is returning is a newly copied object. The state is updating correctly, just the sync to poach is not working as intended.

Comment: state[action.key] = action.value;
            return {...state}

Comment: state[action.key] = action.value;
            return {...state}

I think the above should be:
    let newState = { ...state, [action.key]: action.value };
    return newState